# Proving the Identity Theorem for polynomials

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, roots

Bob tells me that the Identity Theorem is the three following statements

1. If a polynomial has infinitely many roots, then it is equal to $0$.
2. If two polynomials satisfy $P(x)=Q(x)$ for infinitely many $x$, then the two polynomials are equal.
3. If two polynomials of at most degree $n$ satisfy $P(x)=Q(x)$ for $n+1$ values of $x$, then the two polynomials are equal.

I do not know how to prove these; I think the Factor, Remainder, and Division Theorems will be useful.

I tried using Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, but it did not get me anywhere.

Comment: Who is Bob and why his statements should be of interest?

Comment: Use number $3$ to prove the second one... Then use the second one to prove the first.  Then all that remains is proving the third one.  Alternatively, prove these in the reverse order

Comment: what have you tried with the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra?
What does it tell you about a non-constant polynomial?

Comment: @user Probably, "Bob" refers to http://www.mathdoctorbob.org/

Comment: Hint : A polynomial of degree $n$ can have at most $n$ distinct roots

Comment: Note that it matters that the polynomials have coefficients over a field (or a domain). So real or rational or integer coefficients will do. But without this condition we have modulo $8$ the polynomial $x^2-1$ has four roots $1,3,5,7$ and factorisations $(x-1)(x-7)\equiv (x-3)(x-5) \equiv x^2-1$, so factorisation is not unique.

Comment: @Peter Is $P (x)\equiv0$ a polynomial?

Comment: @user Yes, called the "zero-polynomial"

Comment: @peter Then probably your statement  is valid only for non-zero polynomials.

Comment: @user I assumed that the degree $n$ is $0$ or positive and not $-\infty$, which is usually considered to be the degree of the zero-polynomial.

Comment: You need to specify the coefficient ring else it may fail, e.g. $\,x^2 = 1\,$ has $4$ roots over $\,\Bbb Z/8 = $ integers mod $8$ since $\,{\rm odd}^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}\ $ (and such rings do frequently occur in number theory - your tag).

Answer (score 0):

For polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb C$, the three facts are easy consequences of the *fundamental theorem of algebra*,  which says that a nonzero polynomial has $n$ ( not necessarily distinct) roots, where $n$ is the degree.

For example,  $n+1$ would be too many roots, leaving the zero polynomial as the only way out.

Comment: The field doesn't really matter. Over any field, a non-zero polynomial of degree $n$ has no more than $n$ roots, since each root corresponds to a degree $1$ factor of the polynomial.